# Facebook closeAndClearTokenInformation

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios6

I having problem with the log out from facebook. It should log out the current user and back to the main page but now It back to the main page but it pop back to the current screen with the empty field that which I already clear using closeAndClearTokenInformation. Anyone please help.Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)LogOutAction {

       [appDelegate readPersonsFromDatabase:kPERSON_TYPE_OWNER withPersonName:@"" withPersonBirthday:NO];
    if ([appDelegate.myIPPersonArray count] > 0) {
        self.myIPPerson = [[IP_PERSON alloc] initWithInternalNum:@"1" personType:kPERSON_TYPE_OWNER personID:@"" personName:@"" personCompany:@"" personAddress1:@"" personAddress2:@"" personCity:@"" personState:@"" personPostcode:@"" personCountry:@"" personEmail:@"" personPhoto:@"" personDOB:@"" userDef1:@"" userDef2:@"" userDef3:@"" userDef4:@"" userDef5:@"" userDef6:@"" userDef7:0 userDef8:0 status:@"0"];
        [self.myIPPerson setPersonCredit:@"0"];
        [appDelegate insertOrUpdatePersonToDatabase:self.myIPPerson];
    }
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: rather that popToRootViewControllerAnimated you can try like '[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];'

Comment: Hi viruss mca,I already try but still the same.

Comment: What does the block you passed to the Session when you originally opened the session look like? When you close the session, that block will get called back with a session state change notification, and if that block does any view controller modifications, it may undo your popToRoot call.